# all toiling like cock-angels

Tags: meaning

> 'Twould have done your heart good, Mus' Springett,  to see the two
>   hundred of us masons, jewellers, carvers, gilders, iron-workers and
>   the rest--all toiling like **cock-angels**, and this mad Italian
>   hornet fleeing one to next up and down the chapel. Done your heart
>   good, it would!'

This is from "Rewards and Fairies"/"The Wrong Thing"
by Kipling.

http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf

I do not understand what "cock-angels" means.

The Note of Kipling Society Web says;

cock-angels perhaps to be glossed from OED:

http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/rg_wrongthing1.htm

What does it mean?

I am glad if someone kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the second source you've provided, the prefix *cock* in this instance is connected to *cocky*, which the OED defines as:

> conceited or confident in a bold or cheeky way.

So it means they worked like bold, confident angels.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is so helpful for me!!

Comment: Could it mean "male angels" instead, as opposed to "gender-neutral angels" and "female angels"?

Answer (score 0):

I find the notion that these builders are somehow 'bold or cocky angels' rather unlikely. Whatever it is, a 'cock angel' presumably has something to do either with 'toiling', or else with the large assemblage of diverse workmen. My hypothesis (for which I have not been able to find a shred of evidence)is that the simile refers to swarming insects, and that "cock-angel" is a dialect form of 'cockchafer', a species of beetle once noted for appearing in great swarms.

Answer (score 0):

To save time and understand the meaning, you can simply replace "cock-angels" by another, less recondite and better-known term, such as "toiling like slaves/ toiling like ants/ toiling like oxen"... in other words, people or things that work hard.
You can find even more examples in an online search by replacing the low-frequency "toiling" by the more common synonym "working". Then, you will find expressions such as "working like a beaver/dog/Trojan/donkey... etc.

Comment: NB: This a a very old-fashioned type of literary English and many native speakers today would also find it difficult to understand. It has little relevance to the actual spoken language of the 21st century.